# How to print multiple lines and make each output line different?

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a script where i can print multiple lines (was thinking with a for or while loop) and every line that outputs is different
like:

```
Output:

Hello.1
Hello.2
Hello.3
```

Is it posible to make with python?

Comment: This question is one tiny little step away from "can you program stuff with Python?"

Comment: Hi, is your question solved? If so, feel free to accept an answer.

Comment: Yes, totally, thanks, i'm new in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid of answering this simple question but here is the answer using a `for` loop

```
for i in range(1,4):
    print ("Hello.%s" %i)

# Hello.1
# Hello.2
# Hello.3
```

Second alternative way is using `format`

```
for i in range(1,4):
    print ("Hello.{}".format(i))
```

Third alternate is using `f`-strings as

```
for i in range(1,4):
    print (f"Hello.{i}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Python 3.6` or above, you can do it like this:

```
def nprint(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(f"Hello.{i+1}")

nprint(3)

output:
Hello.1
Hello.2
Hello.3
```

[image]